# How to pass javascript array with HTML data into php array

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I want to pass array in javascript in php. but I only received an html, not an actual array when I put an html in my array.

This is what it look like in Javascript console before passing it on my php.

[image]

this is my code on my form, I just put it on my `name="options"`

```
<form ...>
        <input type="hidden" name="options" value="">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    ...

     $("form").submit(function(e) {
        // e.preventDefault();
        var options = $('.options li').map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();

        // console.log(options);
        $(this).find("input[name=options]").val(options);
    });

     ...
</script>
```

on my Laravel

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request->options;
}
```

and when I receive on my PHP Laravel post it form into html,
this is what I received. not an array.

[image]

Comment: I don't think your question is very clear. Unfortunately I am unable to understand what you are talking about. You say "what it look like in Javascript" and then provide a screenshot of your console. Why not provide your actual JS and its output? In PHP you receive "not an array". What does that mean? I don't see any PHP anywhere. And then your result is a screenshot of your page. How did you produce that? What is the source of that HTML? Why is that not what you want?

Comment: can you show full code lines? for example, the `.options li` values...

Comment: I want to get array in javascript, and receive it on php with array also, not pure html.

Comment: Show your PHP code too.